# Should I need to customize the generated dummy app in a Rails 4 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

When you generate a Rails engine, one generated product is a complete basic Rails application under `test/dummy`. It makes sense that you'd want to be able to test the engine in the context of an application, but to my surprise the `test/dummy` application seems to be required even for non-test activities like `rake db:migrate`.

I tried removing references to the dummy application from the `Rakefile`, but it seems to be hard-coded into the engine system (see e.g. references to `APP_RAKEFILE` in [`engine.rake`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/railties/lib/rails/tasks/engine.rake)).

I'm trying to convert a Rails application into an engine, and running into various problems with configuration, load order, etc. When I place breakpoints and look at the call stack, it looks like at least some of the issues are differences between the configuration scripts (e.g. `boot.rb`) in the original app vs. the generated dummy.

Can someone explain why the dummy app is required and what function it serves? Should I expect to get away with using the 'original' generated dummy, or is modifying/customizing it inevitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't have to touch the dummy app. The dummy app provides a barebones application to run your engine in (remember, an engine cannot run on its own). It is used as the application when you try to do "application level" stuff like run rake tasks or tests within the root of an engine. This way the engine remains self-contained, and doesn't have to rely on an external application to provide the context in which the engine should run. I believe the dummy app is only used for rake tasks and test frameworks.